# Data Extract Audience Studio Format

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-extract

We are currently implementing Audience Studio, one piece needed in our project is a [first-party import](https://konsole.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214918988-First-Party-Data-Import). My initial thought for this was to use a data extract activity in the marketing cloud to do this as a daily job. I am trying to figure out if the Data Extract activity can be manipulated to model the data needed to work with SF Audience Studio. Here is an example of how the data needs to be structured:

```
User1234^gender:male;age:18-24;interest:fishing
User2345^gender:female
User3456^age:35-44
User4567^gender:male;interest:fishing,boating
```

Any help would be appreciated! Hopefully, as the products become more integrated this will be a native feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to model your output in this fashion. Extract output formatting is pretty limited.

For some reason you even need to raise a support ticket to enable UTF8 encoding.

However, there are quite some "hidden features" not documented anywhere that can be activated through support.

As DMP integrations don't come very often this might very well be one of the cases where the extract format must be enabled by support to not confuse users with options most customers won't need.

So, opening a ticket with support should be your first approach to this.